# Importing object to several files makes converts function into { [Symbol(__esModule)]: true } in the first loaded file

Tags: javascript

I have a `Role` class that defines some role. Then, I create class instances and export them as an object `{ roleName: roleInstance, ... }`

Then I import this object in several files to perform some validation on a user.

**The problem:**

`/Roles/index.js`

```
export default {
  role1: instanceForRole1,
  ...
};
```

I import object with roles into several separate files where I define and then export helper functions.

`/orders/helper.js`

```
import roles from 'path/to/role object';

export default args => {
  ...
}
```

These helper functions when imported into other files somehow convert functions in those files into `Symbol`

```
import helper from 'path/to/helper';

export default args => { // this function will become a Symbol
  ....
}
```

First loaded file with imported helper becomes `{ [Symbol(__esModule)]: true }`. Files that are loaded after, are functions.